# Watson Conversation as an alternative to Watson NLC?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Can Conversation be used as an alternative to NLC? We tried using the same corpus and class names as the intent. 
We compared the results from NLC and Conversation. The Conversation gave 25% error for a document that was rightly classified by NLC
Has anyone tried this approach earlier? Any help is welcome

Answer (score 4):

Neither Conversation or NLC are document classifiers. They are designed to classify questions to a particular intent.

If you are using as it is intended then you can use NLC or Conversation.

They have different learning models. Conversation allows you to customise your model with entities and complex dialog trees.

---

To add to this, Conversation and NLC use two very different scoring methods for confidence. NLC is Relative scoring, while Conversation is absolute scoring. More details here.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/irrelevant_utterance.html

Comment: Thanks Simon  ....  Yes - We are trying to classify text to a particular intent. We have not tried customizing with entities - we will explore this option and get back with our findings.

Comment: Classifying text that is a question? Not a passage of text from a document?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - What I meant was that we have a document which has been divided into sections/passages.

Comment: Same comment applies.  Conversation (and NLC) are both meant to classify utterances, and provide the intent of the writer (or speaker).  If you're trying to classify and break down a document, then this isn't really the tool to be using.
What is your use case?  What is it that you are trying to do?  There may be an easier/better way to use some of the other Watson services to accomplish your goals.

Comment: @DanielToczala yep. Discovery Service (optionally with WKS) would be a better solution for document classification. Or if on-prem/PII requirements then WEX.